# Expectation of exponential of Gaussian random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

Let $X$ be an $(N, M)$ random Gaussian matrix where $M<N$. For a given vector $v$, I want to estimate the expectation of:
\begin{align}
E\left[ {{v^T}X{X^T}{v}} \right]
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
E\left[ {{e^{ - {v^T}X{X^T}{v}}}} \right]
\end{align}

Comment: Are the entries of X iid Gaussian variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose $XX^T = O^T \Lambda O$ with $O$ an $M\times M$ orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda={\rm diag}\,(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots \lambda_M)$ the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Define $w=|v|^{-1} Ov$, then
$$v^T XX^T v =|v|^2 \sum_{m=1}^M \lambda_m w_m^2.$$
The matrix $XX^T$ has a [Wishart distribution,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) with independent $O$ and $\Lambda$. It follows that the $w_m$'s are independent Gaussians with mean zero and variance $1/M$. The probability distribution of the $\lambda_m$'s is
$$P(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots\lambda_M)\propto \prod_{m=1}^M e^{-\lambda_m/2}\lambda_m^{(N-M-1)/2}\prod_{i<j}|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|,$$
with $E[\sum_{m}\lambda_m]=NM$.

This gives
$$E\left[ {{v^T}X{X^T}{v}} \right]=|v|^2 N.$$
The expectation $E\left[\exp(- {{v^T}X{X^T}{v}}) \right]$ can be evaluated by integration for small $M$,
$$E\left[\exp(- {{v^T}X{X^T}{v}}) \right]=\int_0^\infty d\lambda_1\cdots\int_0^\infty d\lambda_M \,P(\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_M)\prod_{m=1}^M(1+2M|v|^2\lambda_m)^{-1/2},$$
for large $M$ it tends to $e^{-|v|^2 N}$.

Comment: sir I didn't understand how did you find the last equation if you give me more detail  if is possible

Comment: for the last equation I averaged $e^{-|v|^2w_m^2\lambda_m}$ over the Gaussian variable $w_m$, which gives the factor $(1+2M|v|^2\lambda_m)^{-1/2}$; then it remains to integrate over the $\lambda_m$'s, with the joint distribution of the Wishart ensemble.

Comment: sir if suppose that $H$ is Complex thus, $ \omega _{_i}^2$ is exponential random variable?

Comment: yes, that would be the case.

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker dir the variance of $\omega _{_i}$ is  $1/M$ or $M$

Comment: its $1/M$ --- the sum of the $M$ variances equals unity.